# Texture appears to be shifted when drawn on screen (XNA)

Tags: graphics, xna, texture2d

Why do my texture's edges contain unwanted colored lines? Texture looks shifted by a part of a pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Texture2d`s can be seen as shifted or misplaced sometimes when you're not drawing the whole texture, but just a part of it via `SourceRect` parameter and the texture's position (`Vector2`) has nonintegral coordinates. It may look like undesired texels showing at its edges.

If you have a texture with 1px purple border, the actual image can appear with sligthly purple edges. You can avoid that by making the texture coordinates integral.

If this code causes trouble…

```
Texture.Position.X = 4.9876f; // 4.9876f is an example of actual value
Texture.Position.Y = 5.1234f;
```

…try adding a cast:

```
Texture.Position.X = (int)4.9876f;
Texture.Position.Y = (int)5.1234f;
```